# Android gradle teamcity testing

Tags: android, testing, gradle, teamcity

I've set my tests for my android projects to run automatically in team city. Tests are running and all is fine, but TeamCity doesnt seem to auto discover the test output. It doesn't catch that tests are being run (doesnt say x/x successfull for example). I've tried adding `--info` to the gradle `connectedCheck` target, but no luck. Any ideas how to achieve this?

I'm using the Gradle Teamcity-runner with the default instrumentation-config in Android Gradle.

Example output from build log for a couple of tests:

[10:11:20][:aproject:connectedInstrumentAFlavorDebug] com.test.sync.worker.SyncResponseValidatorTests > testPermanentErrorResponse[Galaxy Nexus - 4.2.1]  [32mSUCCESS  [0m

[10:11:20][:aproject:connectedInstrumentTestAFlavorDebug] com.test.sync.worker.SyncResponseValidatorTests > testSuccess[Galaxy Nexus - 4.2.1]  [32mSUCCESS  [0m

Comment: How do you have this configured in TeamCity? Do you use Gradle TeamCity runner? How the tests are run in Gradle? If you can provide full TeamCity build log that might help to look into the issue.